# Recursion in a function that counts specific words in a text

Tags: python, function, recursion, count

I have a problem with making a recursion out of this piece of code(pyhton):

this is a code that counts the word in the list

```
def count_words(self, word):
    count = 0
    for line in self.lst:
        if word.lower() in line.lower():
            count += 1
    return count
```

line is here a variable that has the sentence of the book

I need to make this recursive and for now i have this code:

```
def count_words_r(self, word, lst, count, length):
    count = 0
    if length < 1:
        return count
    else:
        if word.lower() in line.lower():
            length -= 1
            count += 1
            return 1 + self.count_words_r(word, lst, count, length)
```

the problem with this code is that the variable line is not defined.

in this piece of code the text is being read and saves it in a list

```
class Document:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        print("New Class")
        text = open(filename, "r")
        lst = []
        for line in text.readlines():
            if line not in ['\n', '/ \n','']:
                lst.append(line[:-2])
        print(lst[0:10])
        
        self.lst = lst
```

I have tried to define the variable line in parameter.

Comment: Will you please show some input data and the expected output data? Your phrase "counts the word in the list" leaves way too much room for interpretation (aka guessing).

Comment: Adding recursion in this case complicates things. Is there a reason you want to do this recursively?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide clear requirements, and your provided code doesn't count as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so this is just something close enough to teach you what you need to know in order to accomplish your goal.

```
# Count how many times "word" occurs in the list "list_of_words"
# The variable "count" is given the default value of zero and then
# the function passes the updated "count" back in when it calls itself
def count_words(word, list_of_words, count=0):
    if list_of_words == []:
        # We've processed the whole list. Break out of this recursive spiral
        return count

    # Pop out the last item in the list and store it as "this_word". 
    # This makes the list smaller and eventually leads to the list 
    # being equal to []   
    # Example:
    #    >>> mylist = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    #    >>> popped = mylist.pop()
    #    >>> mylist
    #    ['foo', 'bar']
    #    >>> popped
    #    'baz'
    this_word = list_of_words.pop()

    # Is our word of interest equal to the word that we just popped?
    if word == this_word:
        count += 1

    # Let's go again!!
    return count_words(word,list_of_words,count)
    
   
words = "this is the end my only friend the end".split()
for word in words:
    line = "it's the end of the world as we know it".split()  
    print(f'count of "{word}" = {count_words(word,line)}') # Notice how we don't provide "count"?
```

Output:

```
count of "this" = 0
count of "is" = 1    
count of "the" = 2   
count of "end" = 1   
count of "my" = 0    
count of "only" = 0  
count of "friend" = 0
count of "the" = 2   
count of "end" = 1
```